# Blazor component inherit, nothing renders

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, components

I want to do simple component inheritance, but I don't see anything when I navigate to /testpage what am I doing wrong?

TestBase:

```
@inherits ComponentBase

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
{
    <h1>@Name</h1>
}

@code {
    protected string? Name { get; set; }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
        GetInfo();
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected virtual void GetInfo()
    {

    }
}
```

Testpage:

```
@inherits TestBase
@page "/testpage"

@code {
    protected override void GetInfo()
    {
        Name = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When your page is compiled the [blank] content is compiled into `BuildRenderTree` which overrides the content compiled into `BuildRenderTree` in `TestBase`.

```cs
@inherits TestBase
@page "/testpage"
// this is content and overrides the content in BuildRenderTree in TestBase
@code {
    protected override void GetInfo()
    {
        Name = "Hello";
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the content declared in the base component you can do this:

```cs
@inherits ComponentBase

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
{
    <h1>@Name</h1>
}

@code {
    protected string? Name { get; set; }

    // This is the correct pattern to add any code to SetParametersAsync
    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        GetInfo();
        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    protected virtual void GetInfo()
    {

    }
}
```

And then declare the page as a class [without a `BuildRenderTree` override]:

```cs
[Route("/")]
public class HomePage : TestBase
{
    protected override void GetInfo()
    {
        Name = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by MrC already explains why your initial approach doesn't work: BuildRenderTree() is virtual. But you can still access base members with `base.`.

So, another way to have mixed base class and derived class content:

```
@inherits TestBase
@page "/testpage"

<h1>Test page</h1>
@{ base.BuildRenderTree(__builder); }  @* render the base class *@
<footer>closure</footer>

@code {
    protected override void GetInfo()
    {
        Name = "Hello";
    }
}
```